# How can we use Dynamics CRM connector in Azure Logic App to retrieve records from multiple entities?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-functions, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

Following is the exact scenario in my Logic App:

I need to fetch records from an entity, but it has many related entities as well, so I need to populate some fields from other related entities. How can I achieve this using Dynamics CRM connector in Logic App?

Also, default max records in Dynamics CRM List action is only 256, whereas my entity is containing thousands of records. what would be the best way to retrieve all records?

Or should I always use CRM REST APIs in Azure function in such scenarios?

Nirman

Comment: From my experience, Logics Apps are not suited to work with a bigger set of data but rather processing single items. You will have to use the [CRM Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logics Apps are not suited to work with a bigger set of data but rather processing single items. Use the CRM Web API instead.